# Athena - SQL to get Customer Count by Order Count

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I have a table with custome rcount and order count as below:

```
Customer   Order_Count
  A               5
  B               7
  C              5
  D              4
  E              1
  F               1
  G              1
```

How do I write the SQL to get customer count by orders? The result would be as below:

```
 Orders      Customer_Count
   7                1
   5                 2
   4                 1
   1                  3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you use `Group by` and get count of customer like this:

```sql
select order_count, count(customer) customer_count
from your_table
group by customer
```